# c++, ask the user to input a set of numbers to sum (unknown number of input), however numbers wouldn't add up

Tags: c++

I want to write a simple program where I ask the user to input a set of numbers to sum. The user can input an unknown number of numbers.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//ask the user to input a set of numbers to sum (unknown number of input)
int main (){
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    while (cin >> value){
        sum += value;
        cout << "sum is " << sum << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I input several numbers, the result always equal to the first number, not the sum of all numbers entered. As in:

> 5 6 7 8
>
> sum is 5

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: keep your return 0 outside of while block

Comment: Thank you so much @KishanKumar!! What a silly mistake. Really appreciate you helping out!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `return 0`. Put it outside of the while block.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You must have to put the print method outside of the loop and the return too.If you want user to terminate at any time he wants then you need to take input at an specific keyword or any other keyword other than the data type(like char at place of integer) , so that it will terminate the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    /*press any key other than number to terminnate*/
    while (cin >> value){
        sum += value;
    }
    cout << "sum is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```